# Why the data is not saved in database?

Tags: iphone, gps

I am trying to save some data from GPS to a local database. First time when i am entering data, it saves all velues. But after clear the data entry sheet it not saved in database. When i quit the app and again save some data, it enters easily. I m confused what happens in my app ? Any help really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmmmm....sounds like a bug in your code :-) Try showing some code so we're able to provide some specific answers and not just guess on what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to debug your app. It seems you are passing some wrong arguments. You need to debug your app. You can use FMDB for all the sqlite purpose. It is very easier to use and very easy to manage.

Answer (score 0):

Have you commited the changes in the DataBase?

Answer (score 0):

Before you decide to use database (SQLite) , make sure you really need a database. If all you need is to persist data and retrive it back (and not querying) , try to do archiving / serialization. See [Serialization vs. Archiving?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288719/serialization-vs-archiving/6260854#6260854) for quick info on them
If your requirement is to have a database, @Rahul's suggestion is the best.